# React Native - Emulator - Hermes library crash - couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, native

After successfully installing the app, when trying to lauch it on the emulator, the following crash occurs. Details below:

```
2020-07-13 14:50:17.365 3375-3722/com.Myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:          create_react_context
Process: com.Myapp, PID: 3375
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:789)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:639)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:577)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:525)
    at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.<clinit>(HermesExecutor.java:20)
    at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutorFactory.create(HermesExecutorFactory.java:29)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:997)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to **android/app/build.gradle**

```
configurations.all {
     resolutionStrategy {
       force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.8.0"
     }
}
```

and make sure that **enableHermes: false**

Comment: Sadly those changes in build.gradle didn't fix it (same error pops). Thanks anyway.